# UUID as id column for a Grails domain class in 5.1.2

Tags: grails

several sources say that

```
import java.util.UUID

class User {

    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned'
    }
}
```

should result in a UUID instead of the numerical guessable number as ID for a domain object.
It basicall works, but the show-view will be broken: the system doesn't find the object by a give UUID - at least in Grails 5.1.2.

I also tried `id generator: 'uuid2'` and `id generator: 'uuid2'` but it is only getting worse.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: "It basicall works, but the show-view will be broken" - If your `"show"` view is looking for a property that dosn't exist, you could change your `"show"` view.

Comment: I though I only changed the type and not the property name. The show view is still the autogenerated one. But I could try to regenerate it, indeed!

Comment: If you mean one generated by scaffolding, I am not sure if that supports a UUID or not.  A view could certainly be made to do so.

Comment: i didn't realize you were using autogenerated code.

Comment: I am lazy, as always 

Comment: It isn't clear what problem you have in your show view but you can look at https://github.com/jeffbrown/rdmuelleruuid as a starting point which demosntrates one way to go about making it work.  I have not tested everything in that scaffolding, but the show view appears to work.  Good luck!

Comment: Awesome, Thanx! Interesting approach. I will give it a try asap

Comment: One thing that changed is the `id` parameter at https://github.com/jeffbrown/rdmuelleruuid/blob/b0c39b3f443e476b5e9443c4bf9f40ad7a88fea1/grails-app/controllers/rdmuelleruuid/WidgetController.groovy#L17-L19 would by default be a `Long` which will need to be a `String` for your use case.  Other actions like `edit` and `delete` would likely need similar treatment.

Comment: That seems to be my problem! I didn't think of the generated controllers!
Thanx for this hint. At least, the show view works now. The save-service is still a challenge, but I guess I now know what to do!

Comment: now the "def save(User user) {" part of the controller will get a user==null.
I guess I will stay with the numerical id :-D

Comment: ok - the switch in the controller form `Long` to `String` fixes the show view for code in the question. But the `save`-controller still doesn't work. The proposed UUIDListener fixes the `save`-controller. So, your code work perfect, Jeff. Thanx. And I learned a lot :-)

Comment: "That seems to be my problem! I didn't think of the generated controllers! Thanx for this hint. At least, the show view works now. " - Makes sense.  I am glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution Jeff proposed in the comments (thanx!) is the following:

In your domain class, define the `id` as `String` and set it to `assigned`:

```
class User {

    String id

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned'
    }
}
```

instead of setting the `id` property directly, create a `Listener` and set the `id` whenever needed:

```
// src/main/groovy/mypackage/UUIDListener.groovy

package mypackage

import grails.events.annotation.gorm.Listener
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.ValidationEvent

class UUIDListener {

    @Listener(User)
    void preInsertEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        if (event.entityObject.id == null)
            event.entityAccess.setProperty('id', UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    }
}
```

In order to pick up the `Listener`, configure it in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
import mypackage.UUIDListener

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    uuidListener UUIDListener
}
```

Last but not least, the old `id` was of type `Long`, the new is of type `String`. The controller methods have the type defined for the action parameters. Change it from `def show(Long id) { ...` to `def show(String id) { ...` and your should be ready to go :-)